# WebStorm autocomplete html code

Tags: webstorm

I'm searching for shortcut in WebStorm for auto completing my html code. So in my case if I write code like `.row` and press something it should automatically write `<div class="row"></div>`.

Comment: If you write `div.row` and hit Tab it will do it. Otherwise how is it supposed to know what element you want that class to be on?

Comment: Omg, yes tab does the trick. I was hitting everything else, just not tab.
even if you write .class it writes you <div class="class"></div>. Write your answer and i will accept it! Thank you

Comment: @jonrsharpe *"Otherwise how is it supposed to know what element you want that class to be on?"* It's a standard behaviour of Emmet -- it will be a `div` tag with that class applied to it.

Comment: @Valor_ `Tab` is default .. but it can also be `Enter` or `Space` .. or even custom key of your choice  -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Emmet`

Comment: @LazyOne oh cool, didn't know that. I thought it only worked tacked onto specific element names.

Comment: @Valor_ You may also want to look at Live Templates (Code Snippets) -- by default it also works with `Tab` -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne nice! Write an answe and i will accept it. thx for help

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Such "transformation" (abbreviation expansion) called Emmet .. and by default it uses <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

But it can also be <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> .. or even custom key of your choice -- you can change it at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Emmet`

---

**P.S.**
For big chunks of code -- have a look at [Live Templates (Code Snippets)](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm).

Comment: Btw, do you know how can we export these code snippets to back up or share them with others?

Comment: @Tung What "code snippets" **exactly?** If you are referring to the standard Emmet abbreviations.. then they are standard ones already (https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) so if your editor/IDE supports Emmet it should have them already. If standard Live Templates -- well, they are standard for IDE (bundled) so no need to share anything. For custom Live Templates that you can create yourself -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory -- they are stored in`templates` subfolder.

Comment: Thank you for the link of abbreviations cheat sheet. It answers my question. If they were implemented by default, we don't need to save the configuration for them.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `Tab` key to auto-complete the code. For example:

Write `.row#row` and press `Tab` key will make `<div class="row" id="row"></div>`.

I think this would help.